# Error for predict() with lmer

Tags: r, predict, lmer

I'm using a leave-one-out method to evaluate how well a model with one datapoint excluded predicts that datapoint (rotating through all datapoints). The code below has successfully run on essentially the same data with a slightly different DV, so I'm stumped as to why I'm getting the error that I'm getting. Here's the relevant chunk of code:

```
dataPennTrim.lmer <- lmer(logDur.PENN~cNewNounDen*ContextCode+
     Vowel.Contrasts+BlockCode+
     (1|subject)+(0+ cNewNounDen +ContextCode|subject)+
     (1|word)+(0+ContextCode|word),
data=pennTrim,
control = lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"),REML=FALSE)
pennPred <- predict(dataPennTrim.lmer, newdata = dataFull2)
```

`dataFull2` has the same columns as `pennTrim`, it just has more rows. Pretty standard use of the `predict()` function. I get this error:

```
Error in t(.Call(Csparse_dense_crossprod, y, x)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a
method for function 't': Error: Cholmod error 'X and/or Y 
have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90
```

Any thoughts about what might be causing this error? I can use essentially the same code with the same dataframes swapping out `logDur.PENN` for `logDur.Manual` (measurements from a different source) and the code gives no errors.

Comment: Googling on "lme4 wrong dimensions" leads me to https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/257 .  Can you install the development version (this fix hasn't made it to a released version yet) and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: Hi Ben, I tried installing the development version as shown in other forum posts (install.packages("lme4",repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos")) but I get a bunch of warnings. Is that install.packages command correct?

Comment: Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.1

Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘lme4’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Comment: if you have development tools (compiler etc.) installed then adding `type="source"` should work.  Otherwise I might have to build a new binary/update the repository.

Comment: No, I don't have any developer tools installed that I know of; I got the same warnings when I added type="source".

I appreciate your help with this.